# vuejs without build production code warning

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vuejs to make a simple page. Although I can make similar page without any framework, I wanted to try vuejs and now it it almost production ready.

Thing is it is simply single js and html file and it throws following warning.

> You are running a development build of Vue.
> Make sure to use the production build (*.prod.js) when deploying for production.

Let's say I want to keep things this way, how do I remove this warning and get single page html and js file?

```js
// main.js
  const { createApp } = Vue

  createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
      }
    }
  }).mount('#app')
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
- index.html
- assets
-- js
--- main.js
-- css
--- styles.css
```

Comment: Your post lacks information on how you are building your application. Are you using vue-cli are you using plain html when does this error occur usw. Without it, it's not reproducible why exactly this occurs for you.

Comment: You don't have to worry about this warning at all. It does not break your application. If you want to get rid of it - simply use the `*.prod.js` version of the Vue script file.

Comment: @Lalaluka, I edited the question. I am not using vue-cli or something. Just plain vuejs in js file.

Comment: I'm not really sure, but I'd bet the warning comes for the source you're using at: `https://unpkg.com/vue@3`. I'd look for a production version from a CDN, I **believe** that'd remove the warning.

Comment: @IVOGELOV, I checked the doc for `*.prod.js`. Unfortunately it wasn't very clear for me with the CDN `unpkg.com`. I later found `https://unpkg.com/vue@xx-version-xx/dist/vue.global.prod.js` to be working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @IVO GELOV, and mentioned in guide [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/best-practices/production-deployment.html#without-build-tools), it is working for me now.

Use below url for production use and to remove the warning.

`https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js`